# How can I call a Python function from Node.js without starting a new session (Selenium)?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, selenium

So what is happening is that I already have a python script that is running selenium. But what I need to do is to call a python function with arguments from node.js to the already running python script without running a new instance of the python script.

For eg. I have a python script called `HelloWorld.py`

```py
import sys
def HelloPal(pal):
    print("Output from Python")
    print("Hello " + pal)
```

How can I call `HelloPal("World!")` to the already open instance of `HelloWorld.py`?

What I thought of:

Referring to [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-python-script-node-js-using-child-process-spawn-method/)

I can send a value of a boolean `callFunc = true;` using `node.js`.
 And in the `HelloWorld.py` :

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
callFunc = False
try:
    callFunc = sys.argv[2]
except:
    print("Localhost URL is not called yet!")
while callFunc is True:
    HelloPal(sys.argv[1]);
def HelloPal(pal):
    callFunc = False

    print("Output from Python")
    print("Hello " + pal)
```

And in the node.js script :

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 

app.listen(3000, function() { 
    console.log('server running on port 3000'); 
} ) 

app.get('/name', callName); 

function callName(req, res) { 
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn; 

    // E.g : http://localhost:3000/name?firstname=Mike
    var process = spawn('python',["./HelloWorld.py", 
                            req.query.firstname, 
                            true] );
    process.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
        res.send(data.toString()); 
    } ) 
}
```

But after testing I have recognized that node.js is opening a new instance of `HelloWorld.py`.

How can I call `HelloPal("World!")` to the already open instance of `HelloWorld.py`?

Comment: I wonder if you're aware that node has selenium too, as well as the much better (IMHO) puppeteer

Comment: Oh that seems awesome. It is just that I am learning python more than node. But it seems that there are some packages that allow me to localhost and send and recieve data to already python sessions. Isn't it ? @pguardiario Do you have any idea about helpfull python packages?

Comment: There's flask I guess, which is similar to express in node. I wouldn't do it that way if I were you though.